# Why does Azure App Service use Windows 8?

Tags: azure

I have been for the past couple of hours debugging a new error (started after updating some NuGet packages or VS).
Now, after finally being able to see the actual error (Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2 **is not compatible with Azure App Service**) I got into the actual Startup error I was expecting (invalid connection string), but this screen got my attention:

[image]

Now, my questions are:

1. Why does Azure use Windows 8? Is there any specific reason why they don't use 8.1, 10 or a Server version?
2. Does it make any difference that the app is hosted on the Free plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does Azure use Windows 8? Is there any specific reason why they
>   don't use 8.1, 10 or a Server version?

Based on my knowledge, Azure APP service is hosted on Server version. Windows Server 2012 version number is also 6.2. More information please refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Client is not suitable for Azure that needs stable operation for a long time. More important, Microsoft does not  maintain Windows 8 now. I don't think Azure will select Windows 8 as a host.

Comment: Well, in that case, why 2012 and not 2012 R2 or 2016?

Comment: I find any article, Azure does not provides about this, but I don't think use client. Version number 6.2 is Windows Server 2012.